# RoutedEvents in WP7 Custom Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, custom-controls, routed-events

In normal version of silverlight you can create an event handler by registering it by EventManager. Windows Phone 7 hasn't got that class. 
 My question is: How to create an event, which will be handled by the parent panels.

My scenario: I've created a custom class with some textbox in it. Foreach I've added my custom behavior, which raises when textblock is clicked. Behavior works like: "When this Textblock in custom control is clicked, please raise a custom event with my custom args (i want to pass them to the Custom Control itself (for example to specify to which VisualState change it)."

Can you help me how to handle my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide sample code of what you are trying to do?  it seems you want to create an event for when the TextBlock is clicked.

Add an event handler to the textblock:

```
public Event EventHandler<RoutedEventsArgs> TextClicked;

// Fire the event
private void OnTextClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextClicked != null)
    {
        TextClicked(sender, e);
    }
}

TextBlock.Click =+ OnTextBlockClicked;

private void OnTextBlockClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Raise event
    OnTextClicked(sender, e);
}
```

Something along those lines I think.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code you pasted I can write in behavior and attach it to the textbox in my custom control(Texblock.Click will change to AssosiatedObject.Click). Now I want click event to be handled by the containers which contain this textblock. I give the behavior parameter with VisualStateName of the parent control. If the textblock is clicked, templated parent will response it and change its visual state to one, that event send in the arguments (args).